TuneD can't verify profile cause of missing configuration(according to the internet)
So I was crusing the Internet, trying to come up with a performant way of setting up KVM Windows Guest setup on my freshly installed Ubuntu 22.04 Host machine, I found this tutorial.
This tutorial shows How Do I Properly Install KVM on Linux. After following each section, I've successfully made it into Optimize the Host with TuneD section. I've ran commands listed here in this section but once I ran;
$ sudo tuned-adm verify

Verification failed, current system settings differ from the preset profile.
You can mostly fix this by restarting the Tuned daemon, e.g.:
  systemctl restart tuned
or
  service tuned restart
Sometimes (if some plugins like bootloader are used) a reboot may be required.
See tuned log file ('/var/log/tuned/tuned.log') for details.

above error occured followed by verify command. Here is complete /var/log/tuned/tuned.log file.
Note that; I'm totaly new to Linux ecosystem, don't know much about it's concepts.

Now it's fixed somehow in Ubuntu 23.10.
